# VSC / Typescript force path-intellisense for variables

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to get the intellisense / compiler checking (no types for ... found) for paths in variables that require & import have ?

Something like:

```
const myPath: Path = "../utils/utils.js";
```